# How do I convert a javascript string to HTML to be displayed in a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

ok I know there has to be a way to do this, but I can't find out how anywhere. I am a newb to jQuery and JavaScript, so I am sorry if this is a dumb question. 
I am calling a cfc (coldfusion) from jQuery and returning HTML. The problem is, when I return the data, it is in the form of a JavaScript string and is being displayed as plain text on the page, instead of being processed as the HTML. Is there a function, or a way to convert the string back to HTML?

Comment: Can you post your jQuery code. Also, are you calling the cfc directly or are you calling .cfm template that invokes a cfc?

Answer (score 4):

This would be how to write html inside of a jQuery element:

```
$('#id_of_element_to_put_html_inside').html(your_javascript_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for [`element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML)?

Comment: innerHTML is the fastest way to go, but can be dangerous if you do not know what the content you are inserting is. Any included script tags will be executed, making your site vulnerable to XSS attacks. I'm guessing the same is true for jQuery.html. The safer, but slower, way would be to parse the content and manually create DOM nodes for it.

Comment: @Adrian: Good point, I was assuming the OP knew what string he receives from the server. [jQuery.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) seems to do some [sanity checking](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L234-236).

Answer (score 0):

`document.write(data);` would be a straight up javascript way of putting the code straight on the page if you're only writing whatever is returned from the cfc. But, as the comment below mentioned, this would need to be the only thing present on your page.

Let's assume though, that you have a page like this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
       <div><p id="dynamicContent"></p></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Your jQuery would then take the data returned by the cfc and add it to the DOM like so:

```
$('p#dynamicContent').html(data);
```

(edited in light of the document.write comment)

Comment: Beware: document.write after the page has loaded (e.g. not inline) will WIPE the page, scripts included

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers. I figured out the issue. This is the function I was using to display my HTML return grom my cfc:
`function displayForm(data){ 
 //alert(data);
 $(".displayCountryForm").html(data);
}`
As it turns out, it was an issue with the CFC. I needed to include the "returnFormat" attribute in the cffunction as "plain". Once this was done, I was able to get my return to render on the page. Thank you all again for your answers.